# nested parent-child REST api call in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, rest

I encountered a situation which requires nested REST api call in node.js
when I got routed rest api POST call,
then during that POST(parent) need to call REST get call(child) inside of POST call.

I am doing this to merge parent's data with child's data then store it in MongoDB

here's an example..(routes/index.js)

```
const variable = require('../app.js');
const { db } = require('../models/user.js');
const async = require('async');
const time_js = require('../time.js');

module.exports = function (app, Transaction_log, User) {
     app.post('/api/transaction_logs', function (req, res) {

          ... get method REST call to certain url(different IP addr) with header option

     }
}
```

have no idea

1. how to call REST API get call inside with header option(x-api-key sting)
2. merge get returned data with post inserted data in one object

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You didn't declare `app` there. I guess it's an Express app

Comment: @Reger I'm sorry I don't get it. I have app.js and declared app there. :S and yeah it's  var app         = express(); using express framework

Comment: What is the challenge here?

Comment: @Qausim have no idea how to call REST API get call inside with header option(x-api-key sting)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a http request library (like Axios) installed and you make use of that library to make the GET request inside your POST request handler. I would advise you make your callback async

```
module.exports = function (app, Transaction_log, User) {
       app.post('/api/transaction_logs', async function (req, res) {
         try {
           const res = await Axio.get(
             'other URL', {
             headers: {
               // header configurations here
             }
           });
           // extract data
           // merge request body and extracted data
           // save in DB
         } catch (e) {
           console.log(e);
         }
     }
}
```